# Studying a code in cryptography

Tags: cryptography, coding-theory

So,i'm given a binary code $C$ with it's generator matrix $G=(A,B)$ where $A,B$ are given matrices. The task is to study the code.

First question: What does this form $(A,B)$ mean? how would $G$ look like?

Second question: When it says,study the code,what should i study? What are the usual things that i should search?

I'm new in cryptography,so any help would be very much appreciated!!!

Comment: The notation $(A,B)$ is something I've never seen, but it likely denotes the [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix). I would guess that you need to say what kind of code it is, i.e., find its length, minimum distance and dimension. However this would make the exercise trivial, so I suppose I also don't know what you're being asked.

Comment: @GitGud,thank you:)is there any chance that i am asked and be able to find a decoding function?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, I'm not familiar with the several different terminologies in coding theory, but if it is what I think it is, then it is also trivial.

Comment: I don't see a cryptography connection?

Answer (score 0):

My first approach

1. Count the number of characters you think makes up the cipher
   Is the count > or < the 26 alpha plus might there be numbers included
2. Count the occupancies of each unique character
3. Can you get a count of the vowels, see if this knowledge developed a possible word

4 can you pick out the characters that MIGHT be a space

5. From this information, try to establish a pseudo algorithm

This is always my first step

Good hunting